# VSTS Agent service doesn't start after reboot, Error: 1069 The Service did not start due to login failure

Tags: tfs, azure-pipelines, azure-devops-self-hosted-agent

I've configured an On-Prem TFS 2017 Build Agent. I set it up to run as a Service using the service account: *...DEV\SRV-....-TFS*.

After a reboot the Build Agent is offline, when I try to start the service I get the error message:

> Windows could not start the VSTS Agent
>   Error: 1069 The Service did not start due to login failure

[image]

This service account has *login as a service* Security Policy:

[image]

I do this odd operation to get the service running (and build agent back online) again, I have to enter the password in the Services Properties:

[image]

This overcomes the **Login As A Service** error above:

[image]

> The account ...DEV\SRV-...-TFS has been granted the Log On As A Service right.

The next message is:

[image]

> The new logon name will not take effect until you stop and restart the service.

So I do that and the Service is running (and the Build Agent back online):

[image]

However, when the server is rebooted (nightly) the service loses its credentials and I'm back to square one.

**How can I prevent the Service Account losing its login as a service rights after a reboot?**

Edit:

I use this same account *...DEV\SRV-....-TFS* on another TFS server and it does NOT have the same problem, it starts up after a reboot just fine.

Comment: Are there any other unexpected errors in event viewer ? Is it possbile that prevented be other processes?

Answer (score 2):

Generally the error messages implies that your Group Policy is explicitly setting which accounts can have `Log on as a Service`, and the accounts you're trying to use aren't in that list. Just double check if the account is in the user list. Try adding it in group policy again.

Another possibility is that other policies overrided the `Log on as a Service` policy. So, just check that.

Please refer to this article for details : [Why does my Windows Service keep forgetting its password?](https://www.coretechnologies.com/blog/windows-services/windows-service-forgets-password/)